# Apps abruptly close and/or keyboard minimizes while using Gboard (6.0 & 7.1)

Tags: gboard, oneplus-3, oxygenos

Ever since purchasing this **OnePlus3t** brand new with **6.0.1** installed, the pre-installed **Gboard** I've been trying to type on abruptly minimizes, sometimes closing the app with it.

I haven't hooked it up to adb/ddms yet but I was wondering if there are any known issues with **Gboard**, **OxygenOS** or perhapse the **OnePlus3t** hardware in general.

Though this behavior occurs mostly in **Messages**, the proprietary Messenger (like every time I use it), it does also happen in Chrome and Jota. Interestingly it only occurs "the first time" the keyboard's been used in a while. After that first "crash", it works absolutely fine. Once the phone has been idle/asleep/un-used (di.fm is usually streaming) for a "while", it happens all over again, severely burning my marshmallows (apples are probably healthier and not so sickening sweet, i just don't want to turn into an iFruit).

The recent **4.1.6/7.1.1** patch installed recently didn't resolve the issue either.

**This device is for all intents an purposes completely stock**. It hasn't been rooted, loaded with a custom launcher, or any other potentially problematic software (I've got a few main stream apps like Jota, di.fm, terminal (installed recently), ...).

I tried turning off some text-prediction features in the Gboard settings to no avail.

1+3t+OxygenOS(4.1.6)+Marshmallow=
[image: 1+3t+OxygenOS(4.1.6)+Marshmallow=]

Comment: Are you sure it is not due to accidental touches to nav bar while holding the phone?

Comment: Wondering that myself I've been paying extra close attention, and slowing down my typing significantly. I haven't yet ruled out edge detection, which triggers often when setting the phone down. I think I toggled *pocket mode* on and off already though.

Comment: Try capturing a logcat while replicating it. If it is a system error or so you may able to diagnose it by looking it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want it to have to come to that after dropping a small fortune, but I don't have many options. It's just going to lead me down a rabbit hole anyway.